# Importance of kasam in Hinduism?

Tags: vedas, puranas, hanuman, dharma-shastras

Is kasam same as vachan/shapath? What if It is taken in a fit of anger, that you won't talk to so and so person and it is taken in the name of your deity. Does it have dharmic importance, if yes,  is there a dharmic way to undo it or get through it.

Comment: Kasam is a  Urdu word, not really related to Sanatana Dharma.

Comment: Kasam basically means promise if I'm not wrong

Comment: Other word would be pratigya.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto as with many good things in Urdu it comes from Farsi

Comment: @iruvar Yeah possible! And Arabic too?

Comment: Qasam is an Arabic word, not a Farsi one. And no, the concept doesn't exist in Hindu scripture.